# What kind of questions are allowed on super user?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on super user about compatibility between windows 7 and sims 2.

https://superuser.com/questions/56548/is-it-possible-to-run-sims-2-work-on-windows-7-closed

It got closed.

Is there another stack exchange site I could ask this question?

Why is a single user allowed to close a question on superuser as opposed to 5 on stackoverflow?

Comment: "Is there another stack exchange site I could ask this question?" <- belongs on http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites/5#5

Answer (score 4):

The question you asked was about a video game.  From the [SU FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> ```
> * computer hardware
> * computer software
> ```
>
> … and it is **not about videogames or consoles**, then you're in the right place to ask your question!

I am not aware of any SO-type site available yet to target videogames, although I can imagine that one would be pretty successful.

> Why is a single user allowed to close a question on superuser as opposed to 5 on stackoverflow?

Diago is a moderator on SU. Moderators have the power to singlehandedly close questions.

Answer (score 4):

I closed this question because it was flagged by various users. As already mentioned and stated in the FAQ no gaming questions are allowed. Also due to the amount of available StackExchange sites regarding gaming this rule will be even more stricter enforced in future.

I am a diamond moderator on SU and therefore have veto voting rights on any questions.

For a list of sites regarding gaming you can visit Meta StackExchange [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites)

<sub>I answered only because I closed the question. The other answers have covered the topic already.</sub>

Comment: Can they erase close votes, too?  I think one of mine got erased.

Comment: No we can't erase close votes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I took the chance this afternoon and bought the new PC for the kids. The guy in the shop said it would work, will find out in a few hours

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me to be an edge case.  We definitely don't want you asking how to play a video game, or how to win one, or the place will wind up looking like Gamefaqs, with game spoilers crowding anything else out.  On the other hand, asking how to run an older program on a newer OS should be SU material.  I think you've got a legitimate question on a sensitive topic.

I'd suggest looking at the documentation to see what it originally ran on, and if possible trying to run it in some sort of compatibility mode.  When you've done that, repost the question without mentioning the program by name, asking for suggestions and assistance.

I don't consider this an end run around the rules, but a way of asking a legitimate question by removing the illegitimate elements.

Answer (score 3):

SuperUser isn't for anything specifically gaming-oriented, and that does include game compatibility with operating systems.

However, there is in fact a place you can ask the question: [SmarterGamer.stackexchange.com](http://SmarterGamer.stackexchange.com). It's one of the new sites built off of the StackOverflow technology, and is a community devoted to gaming in all forms (computer, console, board, role playing, etc).

Comment: Thanks for that. I created an account on SmarterGamer. I see that Jon Skeet is everywhere, he is one of the top answers there also.

Comment: Indeed. But (at least for now; it won't last long) I actually out-rep him there. Lucky me he hasn't gone over to http://autos.stackexchange.com yet ... ;-)